# Teradata: Keep a random single row per column value

Tags: sql, teradata

Suppose I have a two-column table (t1) with the following rows:

```
id   animal
---- ------
1    dog
1    pig
1    donkey
2    cow
2    horse
2    dog
2    donkey
```

Now, I want to retain only one row for a given id.  I could do a minimum or maximum along with a group-by:

```
create table t2 as (
    select id, min(animal)
    from t1
    group by id
) with data unique primary index(id);
```

Is there a way to get a random row for each id?  Something that is less predictable than a min or max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, animal
from t1
qualify row_number() over (partition by id order by 1) = 1
```

This is not real random, to get a truly random result you need:

```
select id, animal
   ,rnd -- without rnd the optimizer removes the Derived Table and throws an error:
        -- [5521] The RANDOM function can not be used in Aggregates or Ordered Analytical Functions.
from 
 ( select id, animal,
      random(1,100) as rnd
   from t1
  ) as dt
qualify row_number() over (partition by id order by rnd) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The first query works.  However, the second query is not working.  Firstly, I think there is a typo - it should be "rnd" and not "end".  Secondly, I get the following error: Error: Failure 5521: The RANDOM function can not be used in Aggregates or Ordered Analytical Functions. on Statement 1.

Comment: Yep, the "end" was an automatic correction :-) That error message is strange, I used a Derived Table to avoid that it, but the optimizer seems to "over"-optimize, i.e. removes the Derived Table.